# PHP and Magic Methods into own class

Tags: php

my code:

```
class Test {

    private $a = 5;

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        // TODO: Implement __set() method.
        echo $name . "#" .$value."<br>";
    }

    public static function do_test(){
        $x= new Test();
        $x->a=5;
    }


}
$x=new Test();
$x->a=3;
Test::do_test();
```

output:

```
a#3
```

The function static `do_test()` doesn't call the magic methods (`__set`). Why?
Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Magic methods are only invoked when the property is *inaccessible* (including if it doesn't exist). Your property is `private`. `Test::do_test` has access to that `private` property, because you're accessing it from a context with the same class. It doesn't have to be the same *instance* (i.e. `$this` or `self`), it just needs to be the same *class context*. A class can access its `private` properties even if it's not the same *instance*. So your magic method is not needed for that access.